# Unable to submit more than one file to google script web project

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Script Web project and added a HTML form which is having multiple file input fields and a few text input fields. The form is working and submitting all the text input every time but having an issue with the file input fields.

1. When my form is having only one file input field then all the text inputs and the file data are submitted to the server and can save the file.
2. When my form is having **two or more file input fields** then all the text inputs are submitted to the server side but the file fields are **having empty object** which is `{}`

The form looks like below:

```
<form id="msForm">
    .......
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="certificateFile" accept="application/pdf" required >
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="otherDocuments" accept="application/pdf" required >
    .....
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS has the following to submit the form:

```
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".next").click(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="Submit") {
     google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(successFormSubmit)
      .withFailureHandler(failedFormSubmit)
      .processForm($(this).closest("form")[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

The server side function in the `Code.gs` file:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  console.log(formObject.certificateFile);
  console.log(formObject.otherDocuments);
}
```

Application is deploying and testing with following project settings:

[image: Google Script Project Deployment Configuration]

---

**Post edit:**
The issue has been fixed by Google in [this bug reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212826471)

Comment: Where is server side function processForm()?

Comment: So far I can only see that your `$(document).ready(function()` is misisng a closing bracket. Can you show your doGet() function, WebApp deployment settings and imported clients-ide libraries (jQuery etc...)?

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka I have added a new bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212826471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This issue does seem to be a bug. While Google is looking at it, I suggest you a workaround:

1. Only logging the bytearray server-side seems to be impacted by the bug, you can still create all files from the blobs passed on form submisison with [DriveApp.createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob).
2. If you need a server-side check to make sure the file blob is not empty, you can create in your form a hidden additional element of a type that is not "file" and use it a placeholder to send information to the serverside.

Sample:

*index.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>     
   <form id="msForm">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="certificateFile" accept="application/pdf" required >
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="otherDocuments" id="otherDocuments" accept="application/pdf" required >

    <input type="text" readonly="true" name="otherDocumentsName" id="otherDocumentsName" style="display: none;">
    
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" />
   </form>
    <script>
      
      document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
          console.log(this.parentNode)
          document.getElementById("otherDocumentsName").value = document.getElementById("otherDocuments").value;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFormSubmit).withFailureHandler(failedFormSubmit).processForm(this.parentNode);
        })
        
        function successFormSubmit(data){
          console.log("success");
        }
        
       function failedFormSubmit(data){
          console.log("failed");
        }
       
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*code.gs*

```js
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function processForm(data){  
  var blob1 = data.certificateFile;
  var file1 = DriveApp.createFile(blob1);
  file1.setName("certificateFile");
  if (data.otherDocumentsName !== "") {
    console.log("not empty")
    var file2 = DriveApp.createFile(data.otherDocuments);
    file2.setName("otherDocuments");  
  }
  else{
    console.log("empty");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @ziganotschka. Your code does not make any sense to me as it is same as mine in functionality.

Comment: If you look closer, you will see that my code passes `this.parentNode` to the Apps Script instead of `$(this).closest("form")[0]`, and if you test it, you should notice that it successfully processes BOTH files. Have you tried to run it?

Comment: The passing object is the same form element. Instead of those document.getElementById also can be used and not making any difference to the `google.script.run` method.

Comment: I provided you a tested, working solution that allows to submit more than one file. If this is not what you were looking for, please disregard it.

Comment: I checked your code and nothing is saved to the drive. The app was redeployed to give drive permission and just checked with your code by completely replacing my code with yours. For a single file, yours and mine both works.

Comment: This is my script file: https://script.google.com/d/1gj2bTvKNNVoJfc8LFiwi3aWznmmA8XmdzeUvpengINLPHOnfpRCl1jg9/edit?usp=sharing It successfully saves both files to my Drive when deployed as `Execute the app as:` `Me` and `Who has access to the app:` `Anyone, even anonymous`. Can you make a copy of my script file, deploy it with the above mentioned settings and see if it works for you?

Comment: I really appreciate and thank @ziganotschka. The project is working for multiple files but it creates an empty documents if you do not select any file and submit. The check if (blob2) is always true regardless of the file is presented or not. Is there a way that to check whether a submitted form contains a non-empty file, in the server side?

Comment: Well due to the bug that you noticed itself, you currently cannot log from server-side the bytearray for forms with multiple file input fields, so a workaround is necessary. The easiest would be to do the check client-side and only send the non-empty files to the server-side, but if this is an issue - as a workaround, you can e.g. incorporate additional hidden fields into your form and assign them values when a file is being selected by the user. You can then evaluate those values on the Apps Script side.

Comment: Thank you again @ziganotschka, Yes I see only a work around at this time and as you suggested, it is better to have a hidden field to capture the status of each file upload fields. Could you please edit your post? then I can upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, I updated it with a sample.